# one point compactification of discrete space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Problem: What is the one point compactification $X^*$ of a discrete space $X$.

In the case of $X$ being finite, $X$ itself is compact so the one point compactification would be merely $X$ $\bigcup$ {$\infty$}.

Now in the case of $X$ being infinite I need to consider two cases.

When $X$ is countably infinite, I have shown that $X^*$ is homeomorphic to {$0$} $\bigcup$ {$1/n$ | $n \in N$} in the subspace topology of the usual $R$.

However, in the case of $X$ being uncountable, I cannot come up with any familiar space that $X^*$ is homeomorphic to. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: By definition a compactification of a space is a compact Hausdorff space containing a dense copy of the original space.  It $X$ is compact then any compactification of $X$ is simply $X$ itself. (Can you prove this?) So if $X$ is finite nothing needs to be added.

Comment: Also, the one point compactification has a definition.  In the special case that $X$ is discrete, it reduces to what Hagen von E. has posted below.

Comment: I rather got the impression that the OP knows what the compactification looks like. And the question is about finding a more familiar homeomorphic space.

Comment: Somebody define familiar. (Seriously, $X$ could be $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb R)))$ with discrete topology; it is hard to come up with anything else but letting $\infty:=X$ and $X^*=X\cup\{\infty\}$)

Comment: LOL, Hagen! ${}$

Comment: Yes I understand the definition of a compactification as Lahtonen pointed out, I'm just curious if there is a familiar homeomorphic space when X is uncountable like when X is countable because the problem from my book just asked me to find a one point compactification of a discrete space and I think the problem is pointless if the answer is merely a copy of the definition.

Comment: @TomCruise Some books introduce the general (Alexandroff's) construction, which applies to arbitrary topological spaces and then show that the result is a compact Hausdorff space if so-and-so; especially, this construction *does* add a point to a finite space. But of course the name "one point *compactification*" is misleading for compact $X$.

Comment: @user135204 Well, there is that (microscopic) jump from "complement of closed compact subsets" to "cofinite"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Fair enough.

Comment: @user135204: I would say that the one-point compactifications of discrete spaces of the various infinite cardinalities are part of the catalogue of familiar spaces for a topologist. You aren’t quite just copying the definition: you have to make the (admittedly trivial) observation that the compact closed sets in a discrete space are precisely the finite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^*=X\cup \{\infty\}$ where the open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are the cofinite sets.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering if there is a homeomorphic space like in the case of countable discrete space but I guess there isn't one when the space is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

One point compactification of discrete topological space is a profinite space. By definition, profinite space is inverse limit of finite discrete topological space. This is equivalent to say compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected. I recommend the book "profinite groups" by Ribes and Zalesskii, [page 89](https://books.google.com/books?id=u8GWrhdhA2QC&pg=PPA89).